# Gradle prefer repository on duplicate entries

Tags: gradle

I have a build tool thats tied the version to the SCM. I can't set the version of a jar when I build it locally. If someone were to change what I'm working on locally it would push the version number (which I can get), but when I publish to my local repo (Ivy) Gradle seems to prefer the external repo.

**build.gradle**

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    ivy {
        url "${System.properties['user.home']}/.ivy2/local/"
        layout "pattern", {
            artifact "[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]"
            ivy "[organization]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"
        }
    }

    ivy {
        url "https://repo/"
        layout "pattern", {
            artifact myPattern
            ivy myIvyPattern
        }
    }
}
```

Without changing the build for the jar that I'm editing. How can I have gradle always prefer the local repo? I have a feeling that `resolutionStrategy` might be the best way, but I don't know how accomplish this.

**Edit 1**

To help clarify, Artifactory has a jar (published by jenkins) with version 1.2.3. I have a jar that I build locally that saves into my local repository as 1.2.3. When I build a project having both repositories in my repository closure (with my local one on top) Gradle seems to pull in the one from Artifactory.

**Edit 2**

Dependency definition

```
dependencies {
    compile ('company:project:1.2.+')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are saying, but Gradle searches repositories in their declared order, and picks the first matching module that it finds (as least as long as fixed versions are used).

Comment: Added more detail. I am not using a fixed version. It's using `compile 'group:package:1.2.+'`. Is that the issue?

Comment: If both repos have the same highest version, I'd expect it to pick the one from the earlier declared repo, but I'm not absolutely sure. There is no other way to influence order. It might be better to distinguish the versions, e.g. by appending a timestamp to the local version and/or giving it a different status (e.g. integration vs. release).

Comment: Alright. I'll go change the ant build file. Soon hopefully we will update to gradle everywhere. Thanks for the info.